# ERROR running force:source:pull: Entity of type 'Workflow' named 'Workflow' cannot be found

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, cli

I am having issues when pulling Workflows using SFDX with VS Code.
The error that I get when pulling in the Workflow (sfdx force:source:pull) is:

```
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'Workflow' named 'Workflow' cannot be found
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

I heard that one fix is to downgrade the sfdx-cli to version 7.26.0 which I am not able to.

Comment: Why can't you downgrade ?

Comment: What version are you currently on that you're seeing this issue? I see mention of the issue on 7.27, but was wondering if you're on 7.30.

Comment: There is now a known issue for it: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001Sitr

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I am on version 7.28.7 I used to be on 7.27.0

Comment: I aso had this issue on 7.28, updated to 7.30 and it was still present. To addres this I uninstalled sfdx completely, and am currently installing 7.26 via npm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid the error on running `sfdx force:source:pull` run the following query through the tooling API and delete any records it returns (easily done in Dev Console):

```
SELECT Id, MemberType, MemberName FROM SourceMember WHERE MemberType = 'Workflow'
```

If you have any workflow metadata which you need to retrieve then use `sfdx force:source:retrieve` to pull these from the scratch org.

Comment: This gives "Invalid type: Schema.SourceMember" when I try to run it in dev console as SOQL.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug that hasn't been fixed, you can follow progress over here:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SitrQAC

EDIT: Fixed as of December 2019